# Async await returns to caller before ContinueWith, but only when exception is thrown

Tags: c#, asynchronous, exception, async-await

Let's say I have two async methods, first one calls second one

```
[HttpPost]
[Authorize]
public async Task<ActionResult> Run(Job job)
{
    await JobHub.RunJobAsync(job);
    return View(job);
}   


public static async Task RunJobAsync(job)
{
    try
    {
        await someAsyncMethodThatReturnsVoidTask()
            .ContinueWith(t => someCosoleLoggingCode());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        someExceptionHandlingCode();
    }
}
```

When no exception occurs, everything in `RunJobAsync(job)` runs to completion before returning to `Run(job)`. The problem is that whenever an exception occurs in `someAsyncMethodThatReturnsVoidTask()`, the control returns back to `Run(job)` before the code in ContinueWith is executed! This also happens if I get rid of ContinueWith and just use await. Is there a way to make sure the code in ContinueWith is executed before returning to caller, regardless of whether an exception occurs?

**Edit**: *I'm not saying the code in ContinueWith() doesn't execute, **it still does**, but only after the calling method `Run(Job)` resumes and the breakpoint `return View(job);` is hit*

Comment: Did you try handling the exception?

Comment: If `someAsyncMethodThatReturnsVoid` returns void, how can you call `ContinueWith` on it?

Comment: (It would really help if you could show a short but complete example - e.g. in a console app - of this happening.)

Comment: Why not call `someCode()` in the catch clause?

Comment: I've made modifications to answer the questions. By returns void I mean Task, not Task<T>. While I do handle an exception, I don't even understand why the exception handling code should run in the first place. Shouldn't ContinueWith swallow the exception?

Comment: Mario: because if there is no exception then it won't run among other reasons...

Comment: The task created by `ContinueWith` (without any continuation options) *will* run regardless of how the previous task ended. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270696(v=vs.110).aspx): "The returned Task will not be scheduled for execution until the current task has completed, whether it completes due to running to completion successfully, faulting due to an unhandled exception, or exiting out early due to being canceled." The problem must be somewhere else in your code.

Comment: guys you're not reading right, i'm not saying the code in ContinueWith doesn't run, yes, it _still_ runs, but the method returns to the caller before it runs. In other words `return View(job)` is hit before whatever is in ContinueWith()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know what's wrong with my code, the line `return View(job);` is being hit before ContinueWith() due to the subsequent form submit that cancels the task (and thus generates the OperationCanceledException). If you come here having a related problem this will only help you if your cancel button is also a submit button.

Answer (score 2):

If you want code to execute in both success and exception conditions, use a `finally` block:

```
public static async Task RunJobAsync(job)
{
  try
  {
    await someAsyncMethodThatReturnsVoidTask();
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    someExceptionHandlingCode();
  }
  finally
  {
    someCosoleLoggingCode();
  }
}
```

Comment: this doesn't work, finally get's executed after return to caller as well. Also, my problem is not the ContinueWith code not being executed, it always is, my problem is that it is executed _**after**_ control is returned to caller

Comment: @LuisFerrao I can only think of one way to "run `someCosoleLoggingCode` after returning to the caller". Are you launching any thread inside that method?

Comment: @dcastro while this is not the answer, somehow this comment pointed me  in the right direction, so thanks for that

Answer (score 1):

The dot operator takes precedence over `await`.  So your code could be rewritten as:

```
public static async Task RunJobAsync(job)
{
    try
    {
         Task firstTask = someAsyncMethodThatReturnsVoidTask();
         Task secondTask = firstTask.ContinueWith(t => someCosoleLoggingCode());
         await secondTask;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        someExceptionHandlingCode();
    }
}
```

I don't know how `someAsyncMethodThatReturnsVoidTask()` is implemented but potentionaly it never returns a task:

```
Task someAsyncMethodThatReturnsVoidTask()
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

In this situation it is obvious that only the first line of code will execute, then jump straight to the `catch`.
All this code would be run synchronously.

Comment: Let's say that's exactly how someAsyncMethodThatReturnsVoidTask() is implemented. First thing that I'm noticing is that control is returned to caller before it even reaches the catch block, in fact it's returned the moment the exception is thrown (I mean before it bubbles up to the parent task someAsyncMethodThatReturnsVoidTask). But more importantly, how can I write my code to make sure someConsoleLoggingcode() gets executed before control is returned to calling function RunJobAsync?